# Convertir mi método en asíncrono

Tags: asincronismo, c#-8.0

Tengo este método que abre la conexión  a SQL Server pero necesito que me quede asíncrono. Hasta el momento todo está bien pero veo que me pide el await.

Veo que me falta algo así:

```
 return await sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

Pero no logro ponerlo por que no estoy ejecutando una consulta sino un procedimiento almacenado:

```
 CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

---

---

```
public async static Task< DataTable> ToList(string nombreProcedimiento, List<Parameter>? parametros = null)
{
    SqlConnection conexion = new(conn);
    
    try
    {
        conexion.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new(nombreProcedimiento, conexion)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };

        if (parametros != null)
        {
            foreach (var parametro in parametros)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parametro.Name, parametro.Value);
            }
        }

        DataTable tabla = new();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new(cmd);
        da.Fill(tabla);
        return tabla;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        conexion.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo el problema, puedes dar más detalles?